# jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap a href and javascript source

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have this index.html and login.html and I use a href to link from index to login. and in each index.html and login.html I import the javascript. However, it seems that only the ones come from index.html that is being loaded. so if I place the js in index.html for the login.html, it works fine. but then, we I place it separately ( another js for login.html that is not in index.html) , it doesnt work

TIA

Comment: In jQuery mobile, you don't make a single file for each page. Alternatively, you should have only one index.html file and all your pages inside. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

Comment: Actually, it perfectly fine to not use the multi-page strategy. The docs even say so: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html.  Multi-HTML page apps must disable ajax either with rel="external" in a element or $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false.

Answer (score 4):

When JQM(jQuery mobile) loads a page it uses ajax to accomplish this. When this happens all code in the `<head>` section is ignored. JQM looks for the data-role="page" part and inserts it into the same dom as index.html. So basically you are doing it the correct way when you add your js in the index.html page.

If you would like to compartmentalize your js code to work for certain pages use this example:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function(){
    // code for #page1
});
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page2', function(){
    // code for #page2
});
$(document).on('pageinit', '[data-role=page]', function(){
    // this code will execute for every page that is data-role="page"
});
```

So go ahead and put all your code in one file. Split your code into appropriate pages like above and include that in your index.html file.

Also if you are using JQM version 1.0.1 with jQuery version 1.6.4(recommended with 1.0.1) use .delegate() instead of .on(). i.e.

```
$(document).delegate('#page1', 'pageinit', function(){  // notice that pageinit and #page1 are switched around for delegate
    // code for #page1
});  // interesting to note that if you use delegate in jQuery 1.7.x it actually just calls the .on() method.
```

**Note** If you were making a web application instead of a phonegap app you would be smart to put your javascript in that one file and include that in every page. This way if someone is following a link or bookmarked your page they will still get the correct javascript file they need.

Anyways I hope that helps you out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a `window.location.href` then it will load the new HTML(In you case it is login.html) If you are using this approach then you have to reload all you scripts again and hence add these scripts in all your .html pages.

```
<script src="cordova-1.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

However if you use the approach recommended by @deadlock then you will just need to load the script once. The later approach is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, specifically how the pages link to each other, and the global config settings you set for app, if any. Like much with jQM, there are multiple practices and strategies supported for page arch.

You can also learn by using desktop browser tools and view the "Resources" to see what and when your resources are being loaded.